# Failed to install Python packaging tools on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

When I tried to install the python packaging tools in PyCharm, I keep getting this error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg

error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory
```

I am not really sure what this means or what it's doing but I tried to make new directory for `src` but not 100% sure where to make it. If you need anything else let me know. I am using Manjaro Linux Kernel 4.19.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command you should be able to install the packaging tools in Pycharm:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Pay attention to install python3-pip if you are using Python3 interpreter in your Pycharm.

It's really works for me.

Comment: upvoted because this resolved the problem in my  case which was identical to the question. I don't understand why it was downvoted